# AudioTrack: Use of stream types is deprecated

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, audiotrack

I am trying to use AudioTrack to play back sample data. I hear no sound from the device but I see this in the logcat:

```
AudioTrack: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
AudioTrack: See the documentation of AudioTrack() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
```

I have tried many examples that I have found online and they all seem to have the same problem. The examples are typically more than 4 years old so the problem must relate to changes in recent Android APIs.

I am currently trying to get this code to work: [github example](https://github.com/m-abboud/android-tone-player)

It's playSound() method looks like this:

```
protected void playSound(int sampleRate, byte[] soundData) {
    try {
        int bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

        //if buffer-size changing or no previous obj then allocate:
        if (bufferSize != audTrackBufferSize || audioTrack == null) {
            if (audioTrack != null) {
                //release previous object
                audioTrack.pause();
                audioTrack.flush();
                audioTrack.release();
            }

            //allocate new object:
            audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
            audTrackBufferSize = bufferSize;
        }

        float gain = (float) (volume / 100.0);
        //noinspection deprecation
        audioTrack.setStereoVolume(gain, gain);

        audioTrack.play();
        audioTrack.write(soundData, 0, soundData.length);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tone player", e.toString(), e);
    }
```

I have had a look at the Android developer documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack#AudioTrack(android.media.AudioAttributes,%20android.media.AudioFormat,%20int,%20int,%20int)) but I cannot work out what needs to be changed. Is it complaining about use of `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC`, `AudioManager.MODE_STREAM` or both? What should it be changed to?

There are no examples of how to playback sample data in the Android developer documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Using the new constructor for the AudioTrack worked for me. You can do it like that:

```java
// first, create the required objects for new constructor
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
rate = audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE);

AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
        .build();

AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat.Builder()
        .setSampleRate(Integer.parseInt(rate))
        .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
        .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO)
        .build();

// then, initialize with new constructor
AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(audioAttributes,
                audioFormat,
                minBufferSize*2,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM,
                0);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).